# Thanos Storage Configuration (S3)- facing issue at thanos-store

Tags: amazon-s3, prometheus, amazon-eks, thanos

I have started the implementation of thanos store with S3 for prometheus for the first time and I am getting this error message while executing thanos-store configuration.
Can someone please help me debug the error?

Message:   level=info ts=2022-02-28T16:37:31.940118532Z caller=factory.go:49 msg="loading bucket configuration"
level=error ts=2022-02-28T16:37:31.940409873Z caller=main.go:132 err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: field encryptsse not found in type s3.Config\ncreate s3 client\ngithub.com/thanos-io/thanos/pkg/objstore/client.NewBucket\n\t/home/circleci/project/pkg/objstore/client/factory.go:82\nmain.runStore\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/store.go:250\nmain.registerStore.func1\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/store.go:195\nmain.main\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/main.go:130\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371\ncreate bucket client\nmain.runStore\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/store.go:252\nmain.registerStore.func1\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/store.go:195\nmain.main\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/main.go:130\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371\npreparing store command failed\nmain.main\n\t/home/circleci/project/cmd/thanos/main.go:132\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:225\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371"

Comment: Do you have a `encryptsse` field in your config file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You need to pass the flag to the config file you've set: --objstore.config-file=<your_file_location_here>

Then, in your config (abbreviated):

2)

```
type: S3
    config:
      sse_config:
        type: ""
        kms_key_id: ""
        kms_encryption_context: {}
        encryption_key: ""
      sts_endpoint: ""
```

https://thanos.io/tip/thanos/storage.md/#s3 for reference. "Field not found" in my experience implies either a syntax issue (missing colon, comma, quote, etc...) or the configuration unexpectedly encountered a field that requires you to explicitly state it at runtime.